# *args and **kwargs

Tags: python

I've a `View`, which calls another function

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        abc(a=1, b=2, c=3, *args, **kwargs)
```

My Function

```
def abc(a, b, c, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

The issue that I'm facing is when I call `abc`, it says `abc() got multiple values for argument 'a'` or sometimes it says `abc() got multiple values for argument 'b'`.

Upon debugging a bit, I found that `args` has exactly 3 arguments, hence (I guess) when `*args` are passed to the function, its clashing with the `abc` arguments. How do I correct this?

Comment: In the event of a clash, what behaviour do you want?

Comment: Multiple ways to cause this: `abc(1, a=1)`, `kw = {'a': 1}; abc(a=1, **kw)`, etc. Somehow what you're ultimately passing in defines a param twice and it can't resolve it.

Comment: add a `print(kwargs)`  inside `abc()` function to see what's going on

Comment: I've found the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

**what is the problem? :**

the `kwargs` dict contains the key `x` as a key.

which makes the call

```
abc(a=1, b=2, c=3, *args, **kwargs)
```

send two values for the param `x`

where x is any of `"a", "b", "c"`

**how to debug:**

try printing your `kwargs`:

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        abc(a=1, b=2, c=3, *args, **kwargs)
```

to be able to debug this. It will have the keys `"a", "b", "c"` in it.

**how can I fix this:** (one dirty solution)

now to fix the problem, just remove the keys from kwargs:

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        del kwargs['a']
        del kwargs['b']
        del kwargs['c']
        abc(a=1, b=2, c=3, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        abc(a=1, b=2, c=3, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
```

Comment: That's going to provide keyword arguments named `args` and `kwargs` to `abc`, rather than forwarding extra arguments.